# Have I destroyed USB power? Ethernet & USB devices powering on & off constantly unless keyboard connected

Tags: usb, hardware, power, usb-power, troubleshooting

I have a rather strange problem. If I boot my Pi with only power, HDMI & and ethernet cable plugged in, the ethernet port and other USB devices will flash on (i.e. the ethernet lights and LEDs on my USB wifi dongle) then off and cycle. I don't believe that too much current is being drawn from the power supply (I've tried 1A & 2A) as I've used the Pi in this configuration before and it also doesn't work with no USB devices plugged in.

However, when I plug in my Corsair K70 to the Pi (it has 1 USB port for the keyboard and one for power - it has lights), I think it powers the other USB devices as the ethernet and wifi dongle work. Also, when attempting a reboot, I noticed that when the (micro USB) power cable is unplugged from the Pi, the Corsair USB can keep the Pi powered on (I think there might be a kernel panic).

I have looked at `dmesg` but all it shows is the devices being found then disconnecting.

```
[ 1072.100878] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 66 // Keyboard being unplugged
[ 1073.644513] ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:505: Not connected    


[ 1073.738090] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 64
[ 1073.738134] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 65
[ 1073.738530] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: unregister 'smsc95xx' usb-20980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet
[ 1073.738632] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[ 1073.928122] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[ 1074.167959] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 68 using dwc_otg
[ 1074.168253] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[ 1074.438519] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9512
[ 1074.438561] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 1074.454142] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1074.454347] hub 1-1:1.0: 3 ports detected
[ 1074.737987] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 69 using dwc_otg
[ 1074.838538] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
[ 1074.838580] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 1074.847715] smsc95xx v1.0.4
[ 1074.929361] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-20980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:19:5a:3a
[ 1076.481477] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[ 1076.482688] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[ 1077.488139] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 68
[ 1077.488179] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 69
```

Then when I plug the keyboard back in:

```
 [ 1083.668000] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 72 using dwc_otg
 [ 1083.668304] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
 [ 1083.938485] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9512
 [ 1083.938527] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
 [ 1083.954005] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
 [ 1083.954225] hub 1-1:1.0: 3 ports detected
 [ 1084.237986] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 73 using dwc_otg
 [ 1084.338525] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
 [ 1084.338540] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
 [ 1084.350547] smsc95xx v1.0.4
 [ 1084.449214] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-20980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:19:5a:3a
 [ 1085.971500] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
 [ 1085.972762] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
 [ 1087.467867] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 74 using dwc_otg
 [ 1087.575897] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1b1c, idProduct=1b13
 [ 1087.575938] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
 [ 1087.575961] usb 1-1.2: Product: Corsair K70 RGB Gaming Keyboard 
 [ 1087.575981] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Corsair
 [ 1087.575998] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 1204302DAE3B9407536FEC40F5001946
 [ 1087.607092] input: Corsair Corsair K70 RGB Gaming Keyboard  as /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:1B1C:1B13.0005/input/input4
 [ 1087.659626] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1B13.0005: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Corsair Corsair K70 RGB Gaming Keyboard ] on usb-20980000.usb-1.2/input0
 [ 1088.408346] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xC1E1
 [ 1088.412633] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

Should I give up on this Pi? (At least for anything that needs USB/ethernet) Have I destroyed some power supply component or is there hope yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a power supply problem. If you get something like this, check that enough power is being supplied to the Pi e.g. with a multimeter; or if you haven't got one, try a different supply and **cable**.

A faulty cable meant that the Pi was not receiving enough/stable enough power and was unable to power the USB.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to backpower the Pi through the USB but I am pretty sure doing this *and* providing power via another means is probably a bad idea -- as in one which may lead to damage.  If that Corsair keyboard is backpowering this way, it may be defective, since that is *definitely* not something that is a good idea to do to a normal computer (plug a voltage source into the USB jacks).

The fact that you can unplug the Pi and have it remain on obviously means it is providing power.  Looking at [the product description](http://www.corsair.com/en/corsair-gaming-k70-mechanical-gaming-keyboard-cherry-mx-red), I don't see any indication that it has some kind of circuitry to play such a role properly; it's also not clear exactly what that "extra power" jack you refer to is.  My guess would be that it was meant to be used either with **both plugs attached to the same computer** (which would be okay; this allows it to get more than 500 mA from a USB 2.0 hub), or else you've confused the "pass through" connector, intended to provide a device jack on the keyboard (i.e., an input), for a second output jack, and because it is wired to the real output, attaching that to a power supply affects the whole circuit.

Whoops.

Either way, powering that from one place then attaching it as a device to another is, again, a bad idea.  It may already have permanently damaged the Pi -- don't do it again with anything else.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to confirm that it was probably dead. Lesson learnt :P

Comment: Kian: Someone may come along with better knowledge of exactly how that could happen -- I'd just guess the 5V regulator is damaged and can't properly provide the ethernet/USB controller (it is all one chip) anymore.  Note that if you are lucky, it could be [polyfuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse) related; try leaving it unplugged for a few days and see if it is okay after that. @Ghanima So no cake for you then.

Comment: Turns out it was just a faulty power cable! Only discovered after I had problems with a brand new Pi 

Comment: I still would not plug that keyboard in using a separate power supply unless you have documentation for it that says that is okay, because if it was back-powering a pi in the way you describe I am sure it was not intended to be used that way.  +/2/3 models can put out 1 A+ over the USB if you set `max_usb_current` (see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/46437/5538), so if you want to plug both lines from the keyboard into the pi do so, but don't put one into the pi and one into a wall wart.

Comment: I don't plan to after that scare! Thanks for the tips!